# Received email addressed to someone else from themselves

Tags: email, phishing, spam

My outlook account received a suspicious email, addressed to somebody else, AW, sent apparently from themselves to themselves.
The sender is not an outlook address, but I guess outlook might be hosting their service.
According to haveibeenpwned my email address has not been pwned, neither has that of the sender.
AW appears to be the name of a university professor.
I have never attended that university, nor do I know the person.
An online search for the linked address leads to a lobbying group in the USA. Also some websites in Brazilian Portuguese.
Clearwebstats claims the website with the linked domain name is safe to browse. (is worth 8.95$ and makes 0.15$ per day)

Why / How is this an exploit?
What is the goal of such an exploit?
How does it work?

[image]

Comment: Please share more details like the entire email header dump. too less info.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1: What is the goal of such an exploit?

This seems like a standard phishing attack to me. I'm sure if you reply, you'll get told some story about how you've won a grant, and they need your back details do to "deposit the money". Typical scam stuff.

---

## Question #2: How does it work?

Sending an email-from-yourself-to-yourself is a common trick **using the BCC field** when you want to send to blast an email to multiple people, but don't want them to see the other recipients.

[image: Using the BCC field to send anonymously to multiple recipients]

Answer (score 1):

You are focusing too much on the `From:` address performing background checks against the person. While Mike Ounsworth's answer gives an example on how this could be done with legitimate mail, it doesn't explain that **anyone could use any email address in the headers** (unless properly protected with [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/overview/)). It's just like a letter: you could fabricate it.

Using others' addresses and reputation is just a part of their techniques to get past the spam filters and make it seem more credible. The university professor AW has probably nothing to do with this, but is another victim.

Instead, you should be focusing on:

**Email body**

- Does it look like a scam? Yes. Are you expecting any "grants"? No. In real world a person you don't know doesn't simply send you mail asking how to send you money for nothing. It's always a scam.
- The email body contains a separate contact address. Have you ever sent an email and asked them to contact you on another address, instead of simply replying to the mail? No. That's a clear hint that the address on the `From` header is fabricated, and they need another address to proceed with the scam.

**Full email headers**

- Not all email headers can be fabricated. Every email server processing the message adds new headers before the existing headers. These `Received` headers can be used to examine from where the message really originated.
- Additional `Authentication-Results` and `Received-SPF` headers may help in deducing whether the source is authorized to send email for the domain, but you must know whose `Authentication-Results` you can trust.
- In Outlook you can view the headers by opening the message into a new window (with a double click) and opening menu File > Properties. The headers are in the "Internet headers" box. Personally I find this box really small for examining the headers efficiently, so I simply copy the contents to e.g. Notepad.